# query to retrieve the id of row containing duplicate value in a field

Tags: mysql

let us assume the table

```
id  usr_id    starttime
1   11        2012-12-12 09:00:00
2   12        2012-12-12 09:00:00
3   13        2012-12-13 12:00:00
4   14        2012-11-12 10:00:00
```

now the starttime is same for usr_id 11 and 12 so I need to retrieve these 2 ids with the same starttime values.

but when I tried using the following query it just displays the first value that is 11

```
SELECT
    y.usr_id
FROM req y
INNER JOIN (SELECT usr_id,, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
            FROM req
            GROUP BY starttime
            HAVING COUNT(*)>1
           ) dt ON y.usr_id=dt.usr_id
```

Comment: Please format your query first and please show your expected output on proper format.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple self join to get the id's with duplicate times;

```
SELECT t1.usr_id 
FROM req t1
JOIN req t2
  ON t1.starttime = t2.starttime
 AND t1.id <> t2.id;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5da4d/4).

Answer (score 1):

try this.. [GROUP_CONCAT(expr)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
select group_concat(usr_id) from req group by starttime
```

Comment: expected result wasnt specified by the questioner,requirements are fullfilled